# Adding help block using form theming

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.7

In my app I'm trying to display form help block using tips from official Symfony2 [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-help-messages). Here is my code:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
  {{ block('base_form_widget_simple') }}

  {{ dump(help) }}
  {% if help is defined %}
     <span class="help">{{ help }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And using this theme:

```
{{ form_row(form.pageTitle, {'help': 'some help'}) }}
```

With this I'm getting error `Variable "help" does not exist`. Any ideas what have I missed?
P.S. I use Symfony 2.7.1.

Comment: I don't know anything about Symfony2. But generally getting an **Varible X doesn't exist** error means that you haven't defined the variable in question. Where do you define your variable help?

Comment: @NatalieHedström, I do understand it. It should be passed via line `form_row(form.pageTitle, {'help': 'some help'})`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry I missed that. Then I'm afraid I can't be much of a help :)
Have you tried debugging to see what is actully passed?

Comment: @NatalieHedström, no problem, thanks for trying to help me :) Well, debugging of twig templates is not that easy (at least for me).

Comment: i think you're mixing up the two examples from the symfony cookbook

Comment: @JessevanMuijden, could you explain what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Form type extension extending the form type:

```
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use ...

class FieldTypeHelpExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('help', $options['help']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['help'] = $options['help'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'help' => null
        ]);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

}
```

Define the extension as a service:

```
acme_app.form.extension.field_type_help:
        class: Acme\AppBundle\Form\Extension\FieldTypeHelpExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

Create a template extending form div layout:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block field_help %}
    {% if help is defined and help %}
        <p class="help-block">{{ help|trans }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock field_help %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ block('field_help') }}
{% endblock integer_widget %}

{% block form_widget %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ block('field_help') }}
{% endblock form_widget %}
```

Configure this template as form theme on config.yml

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'Form/fields.html.twig'
```

Now you can use it when render the a field on a template:

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, { 'help': 'this is help' }) }}
```

Or in your Form type:

`$form->add('name', 'text', ['help' => 'this is help'])`;